# Argument value different inside called function

Tags: c#, multithreading, multitasking

I am using the code below for creating multiple tasks in C#:

```
private static List<Task> _taskList = new List<Task>();
private static ConcurrentQueue<string> cred = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

private static void TaskMethod1(string usercred)
{
    // I am doing a bunch of operations here, all of them can be replaced with
    // a sleep for 25 minutes.
    // After all operations are done, enqueue again.
    cred.Enqueue("usercred")
}

private static void TaskMethod()
{
    while(runningService)
    {
        string usercred;
        // This will create more than one task in parallel to run,
        // and each task can take up to 30 minutes to finish.
        while(cred.TryDequeue(out usercred))
        {
            _taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => TaskMethod1(usercred)));
        }
    }
}

internal static void Start()
{
    runningService = true;
    cred.enqueue("user1");
    cred.enqueue("user2");
    cred.enqueue("user3");
    Task1 = Task.Run(() => TaskMethod());
}
```

I am encountering a strange behaviour in the code above. By putting a breakpoint at line `_taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => TaskMethod1(usercred)));`, I am checking value of `usercred` every time `TaskMethod1` is called and it is not null while being called but in one of the cases the value of `usercred` is `null` inside `TaskMethod1`. I have no clue how this could be happening.

Comment: I suspect that you got [captured variable problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/271440/12833205). Please, add code that shows all usages of the variable *arg1* inside method *TaskMethod*.

Comment: Edited with the code that shows the usage of the variable inside TaskMethod.

Comment: Can you please change `while(cred.TryDequeue(out usercred)) { _taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => TaskMethod1(usercred))); }` to `while(cred.TryDequeue(out usercred)) { var uc = usercred; _taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => TaskMethod1(uc))); }` and let us know if the problem goes away?

Comment: Is this a problem that only occurs when the debugger is attached, and goes away when you run your program with Ctrl+F5 (without debugging)? I am asking because you mentioned a breakpoint, and the debugger in not 100% trustworthy with multithreaded code.

Comment: Also are you aware that the `TaskMethod` method creates a tight loop?

Comment: Sorry, @TheodorZoulias but what do you mean by tight loop?

Comment: The `TryDequeue` will return `false` most of the time, so the thread will keep spinning non-stop, in essentially a `while(runningService) {}` loop.

Comment: yeah, there are conditions to not let that happen, I have put. But this can not the reason for the problem I am facing right, or can it be?

Comment: No, that's certainly unrelated. But I had to mention it because there are cheaper ways to produce heat than using spinning CPU cores. :-)

Comment: @Enigmativity, it seems to have worked what you suggested but I am still not sure of the reason, Can you please explain why it? (I am stress testing it but it passed the basic testing.)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Task.Run` where in you are using variables from while loop. You are not passing it to the task. So, by the time task executes, its value gets changed.

You should use

```
while (runningService)
{
    string usercred;
    // This will create more than one task in parallel to run,
    // and each task can take upto 30 minutes to finish.
    while (cred.TryDequeue(out usercred))
    {
        _taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew((data) => TaskMethod1(data.ToString()), usercred)
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the `Task.Factory.StartNew` method instead of `Task.Run` for the reason of passing an argument [is considered](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/) a performance optimization technique (avoids closures for performance-sensitive code paths). For normal application code the `Task.Run` is preferable because it's more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You should [declare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier#calling-a-method-with-an-out-argument) the `usercred` variable inside the inner `while` loop, so that the lambda inside the `Task.Run` captures a separate variable for each loop, and not the same variable for all loops.

```
while(runningService)
{
    while(cred.TryDequeue(out var usercred))
    {
        _taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => TaskMethod1(usercred)));
    }
}
```

As a side note, I would consider using a [`BlockingCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) instead of the `ConcurrentQueue`, to have a way to block the current thread until an item is available, so that I don't have to worry about creating inadvertently a tight loop.

Answer (score 0):

The following change solved the problem.

```
private static void TaskMethod()
{
    while(runningService)
    {
        string usercred;
        // This will create more than one task in parallel to run,
        // and each task can take up to 30 minutes to finish.
        while(cred.TryDequeue(out usercred))
        {
            var uc = usercred;
            _taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => TaskMethod1(uc)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Both this an Theodor's answer solves the problem. Your code was re-using the same reference to `usercred` so if the task did not start fast enough the next `cred.TryDequeue(out usercred)` would overwrite the value of `usercred`. What made it `null` is still a mystery to me. But I was curious if my suggestion would work and it did.